# Javascript - executing a function only when input value length goes from 3 characters to 2 characters?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a certain function if the input element value goes from 3 characters to 2 characters.

For example :
If input value goes from "doe" to "do" - fire **someFunc()**

But I don't want to fire someFunc() if the input value was empty and then the user typed 2 characters.

The logic is something like this

```
let inputValue = e.target.value

if(inputValue.length === 2 && previousValue.length === 3) {
    someFunc()
}
```

How to get previous value of input element if the input value changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the previous value. I'm using a closure here but you can use any other scope mechanism.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#len');
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let previousValue = input.value;
  return function(e) {
    let nextValue = e.target.value;
    if (previousValue.length === 3 && nextValue.length === 2) {
      alert('You just went from 3 to 2');
    }
    previousValue = nextValue;
  }
}());
```

```html
<input id="len"></input>
```

Comment: This is working, thanks! How would you do it in React?

Comment: It wouldn't be that different. In fact, you could take the function passed down to the `addEventListener` and copy that straight up as the `onChange` property and it should work. Though you might want to save either value (or both) as part of the state.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (done in jQuery but you can use whatever library/framework to the same end). Let me know if it works for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let prevCount = 0;
  
  $("input").change(function(e){
    if(prevCount === 3 && e.target.value.length === 2){
      //Fire function here
      console.log('working')
    }
    prevCount = (e.target.value.length)
  })
})
```